# "/var/docker/server.pem: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker

I have Docker version 18.09.7 installed on ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VMWare Workstation 14 Player 14.1.1 on Windows 10 Home. When I try to run `sudo dockerd`, it returns the following:

> Failed to create API server: Could not load X509 key pair (cert: "/var/docker/server.pem", key: "/var/docker/serverkey.pem"): open /var/docker/server.pem: no such file or directory

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you find any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

***IMPORTANT: Make sure you have write permissions on the folder /var/docker/ before you even try, use this `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/docker/`***

---

You need to use OpenSSL to generate your certificate files, this is actually pretty *easy* just run this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout /var/docker/serverkey.pem -out /var/docker/server.pem
```

> **(Note that I already modified it for your server path including the x509 option! So just run it and report back if the `sudo dockerd` is now working)**

---

Looks like the first option did not work for you, Make sure you have permissions like mentioned above, Try this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout serverkey.pem -out server.pem
```

---

You will also be glad to know you can run this command: `sudo su` in order to always be a superuser therefore you will not need to type `sudo` before every command...

---

*`If that helped you please mark it as the answer by clicking the V button under the upvotes for other people to know :)`*

Comment: That returns the following:
`.......................................+++
........+++
writing new private key to '/var/docker/serverkey.pem'
/var/docker/serverkey.pem: No such file or directory
140301209015960:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:406:fopen('/var/docker/serverkey.pem','w')
140301209015960:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:408:
`

Comment: Try to cd somewhere safe (cd ~) and then run it without the path /var/docker/ - (openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout serverkey.pem -out server.pem) and then use "mv serverkey.pem /var/docker/serverkey.pem" - "mv server.pem /var/docker/server.pem" to move the files if they were even generated back to the docker folder if it even exists.. and of course make sure your machine is up to date (apt-get update or something) AND that openssl is installed and updated. (apt-get install openssl)

Comment: also, make sure you have write permissions on the folder /var/docker/ before you try my other solution (sudo chmod -R 777 /var/docker/)

Comment: directory `/var/docker/` does not exist ?

Comment: I think they might have changed that to `/var/lib/docker/`